# Visual Studio Application dependency

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio, dependencies, console-application

I am making application in Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express Edition.
After I compile the program and then copy the .exe to my friend computer, but when I want to run it, the computer tell me that .NET Framework is needed.

Previously I work with MinGW and it's only console application, when I copy to another computer the program need "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll" so I just copy that file and it's work.
But when I make the Windows Form Application or Console Application the program need the .NET Framework.

My question is, do my friend have to install the .NET Framework to run my application or I only need to copy one or several files to fulfill my application dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the .NET Framework and I suspect the C++ Runtime & Redistributable as well. For any recent system (Windows Vista or newer) you'll find that these are prerequisites of the operating system and that they're almost certainly installed (.NET Framework 3.0 or better). Windows XP shipped with an old version of .NET and would require you to install the newer version of the Framework (Windows Update pushes the framework by default, unless you suppress the installation).

Which version of the [framework shipped with which version of Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history) can be found here.

There are 3rd party commercial solutions available that can link the whole .NET framework dependency into your application. [Salamander .NET Linker](http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/) is one and the [Spoon.NET platform](http://spoon.net/studio) (previously Xenocode) is another. There might be others, but these are the ones I've seen used in the past.

Comment: It seems the free one is Salamander .NET Linker, but I don't know how to use it. Could you please show me the tutorial, I never use this before. I really want to make a WinForms Application. Previously I use WinAPI to create a GUI application for windows, but I'm getting tired of tons of code that I needed even for making the simplest GUI. At least could you give me a link to the tutorial for Salamander?

Comment: I'd recommend installing the .NET framework or creating an installer that installs it if it isn't present. The Site for Salamander has a short tutorial: http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/ I personally don't have any experience with setting this up.

Comment: Plus, if I read it correctly, the license starts from $1249 per developer http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/pricing.html